# Code in Petzold's Programming Windows (Making Window Error)

Tags: c, windows, winapi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, WPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int    iCmdShow)

{
static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("HelloWin");
HWND  hwnd;
MSG msg;
WNDCLASS wndclass;

wndclass.style =  CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc ;
wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0 ;
wndclass.cbWndExtra= 0 ;
wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL,IDC_ARROW);
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH);
wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
{
   MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
}
hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,
                    TEXT ("The Hello Program"),
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    hInstance,
                    NULL);
                    ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow);
                    UpdateWindow (hwnd);
                    while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
                    {TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage (&msg);
                    }
                    return msg.wParam;

}


LRESULT CALLBACK Wndproc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HDC  hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
RECT  rect;

switch (message)
/*case WM_CREATE;
PlaySound (TEXT("hellowin.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_ASYNCE);
return 0; */
{case WM_PAINT:
hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd,&ps);
GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect);
DrawText (hdc, TEXT ("Hello, Win 98!"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER);
EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
return 0;

case WM_DESTROY:
PostQuitMessage(0);
return 0;
}
return DefWindowProc (hwnd,message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Hello,
I have tried to copy out of Petzold's Programming Windows. And for the most part it went well. But when I tried to compile I got an error for the wndclass.lpfnWndProc. I tried looking up if it could be an os issue, but to no avail. Btw the error said something about invalid conversion to LRESULT..... but I can't find any resolution to it, so I am wondering if it is an os issue (being long point or something) or what. And if there is any sites that might help better "modernize" the book, it would be appreciated. Thanks 
Zach

Comment: `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, WPARAM);` the last `WPARAM` should be `LPARAM`. There might be other problems.

Comment: There are, the real function name is Wndproc, lower-case p.  Pick good names.  And get a decent text editor that can indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing these two typos:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc ( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc ( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
```

I found that the code compiles and runs just fine:

```
C:\TEMP>cl test.c user32.lib gdi32.lib
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe
test.obj
user32.lib
gdi32.lib

C:\TEMP>test.exe
```